# Wrong confidence interval in R

Tags: r, self-study

I have independent 2 samples (both with $n = 200$) and i want to show that the true mean of sample b is higher than the true mean of sample a i.e. $H_0 : \mu_B \le \mu_A$ and $H1: \mu_B \gt \mu_A$.

I wanted to conduct a two sample t-test but since the true mean and variance are unknown i did a F-Test beforehand. The results of the F-Test were, that $\sigma^2_A = \sigma^2_B$.

Because of that i ran the aforementioned t-test in R with following parameters:

```
t.test(B,A, alternative="greater", var.equal = TRUE, paired=FALSE, conf.level=0.95) 
output:
           Two Sample t-test
data:  B and A
t = 0.33934, df = 398, p-value = 0.3673
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is greater than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1062.14      Inf
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 8545.895  8270.625
```

I calculated the test-value by hand and had the same result for t. The means of A and B are correct too, but i dont understand the confidence interval. As far as i know the critical value for a right sided test is $t_{398;0.95} = 1.649$ and because of that id keep the null hypothesis since $t = 0.3393 \ngtr 1.649$. But if i were to follow the confidence interval in R id have to reject it, which seems odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add to/expand on @abstrusiosity's answer:

1. As mentioned above, 0 falls between `-1062.14` and `Inf` - so if you were using the confidence interval to make null hypothesis testing decisions you *would* fail to reject the null in this case. (assuming the null is that the difference is not different from 0).
2. The `Inf` is a result of your one-sided test. You don't *really* care about the upper bound of the CI in a `>` one-sided test - just that the lower bound is above 0. You get the same behavior with one-sided tests in the opposite direction. If you run the code below, you'll get `-Inf` on the lower bound of the interval when the directionality of the test is reversed.

```r
A <- rnorm(100)
B <- rnorm(100)
t.test(A, B, alternative = 'less', var.equal = TRUE, paired = FALSE, conf.level = .95)
```

3. If you want the symmetrical 95% CI you can run the code below. This CI would map on to a two-sided p-value.

```r
# I've omitted `alternative` as the default is "two-sided"
t.test(A, B, var.equal = TRUE, paired = FALSE, conf.level = .95)
```

You can change the interval to `.90` to get the LB or UB relevant for your directional hypothesis *and* get a symmetrical confidence interval around the mean difference.

Comment: Okey thank you, apparently there are many different options, my problem seemed to be interpreting the output correctly

Comment: No problem and no worries. It can be tricky to marry the technical coding with the interpretations - especially when the default outputs don't always perfectly align with what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The result from R says you don't reject the null.

The result gives you the confidence interval of the difference.  It says $-1062.14 \lt \mu_B-\mu_A \lt \infty$.  That means $\mu_B$ could be less than $\mu_A$ and so you cannot reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: So my results aren't opposite at all ? I think i kinda got you but its not quite intuitve for me; is there any way to output the critical value or another way to see that the null hypothesis is not being rejected ?
Edit: So does -1062.14 mean that its a possible outcome for the difference and thus $\mu_A > \mu_B$ ?

Comment: This is a one-sided confidence interval bounded on the low end, and that bound is less than zero.  That means the data is consistent with $\mu_A \gt \mu_B$ and also $\mu_A \lt \mu_B$.  No clear answer about which is bigger.